# Match everything outside of two strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching

For an **input** of

```
*something here*another stuff here
```

I want to match everything that's outside of the two asterisk (*).

Expected **output** after regex:

```
another stuff here
```

I figured out how to match everything inside of the (*) `/(?<=\*)(.*)(?=\*)/` but I can't match everything outside. Noticed that I don't wish to match  the *.

Comment: Why not remove `*...*` ? `s.replace(/\*[^*]*\*/g, '')`

Comment: this is a really good idea but I want to remove the * also.

Comment: Yeah, you get `another stuff here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove substring(s) between asterisks and trim the string after:

```js
s.replace(/\*[^*]*\*/g, '').trim()
s.replace(/\*.*?\*/g, '').trim()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jt0pX0/1).

*Details*

- `\*` - an asterisk
- `[^*]*` - any zero or more chars other than an asterisk
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (*NOTE: if you use `.*`, you will get an unexpected output in case when the string has multiple substrings between asterisks*)
- `\*` - an asterisk

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
console.log("*something here*another stuff here".replace(/\*[^*]*\*/g, '').trim())
// => another stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` the string with `* anything *` and then `join` the string to get the result.

```js
const mystring = "*something here*another stuff here";

const result = mystring.split(/[*].*[*]/).join("");
console.log(result);
```